# Maximal ideals and prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I think there are 3 ideal and maximal primes:

$\langle(0,1)\rangle$ since factor group over $\langle(0,1)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is field and integral domain.

And same reason for $\langle(1,0)\rangle$ .

How about $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ ? I think factor group $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) / \langle(1,1)\rangle$ is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and therefore $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ is also maximal and prime ideals. but answer key only states that $\langle(1,0)\rangle$ and $\langle(0,1)\rangle$ are answer.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: It should be Z2 ... Not Z/2

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1,1)$ is the identity element of the ring, so any ideal containing it contains the whole ring.  You're quotienting out by the **subgroup** generated by $(1,1)$, which is not the same as the **ideal** generated by it.

Answer (score 0):

You have four elements:
\begin{align}
\langle(0,0)\rangle&=\{(0,0)\}\\
\langle(1,0)\rangle&=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}\\
\langle(0,1)\rangle&=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}\\
\langle(1,1)\rangle&=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}
\end{align}
As soon as you add an element to one of the four sets, the generated ideal is already in the list. So this is the full list.

Two of them are prime, the other two aren't.

Your computation of $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ is wrong: $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is not an ideal.

Comment: Thanks. Then, what is the general way of finding prime ideals and maximum ideals. I usually think of any subgroup whose factor group is isomorphic to Zp (Since Zp is a field). For instance, Z2 x Z4, I think one prime and maximal ideal is <(0.1)>  since factor group is isomorphic to Z2. But there is one more prime and ideal maximal which is not generated by any element in Z2 x Z4. How can I find this?

Comment: @Nancy For small rings you can go by exhaustion, adding elements to principal ideals until you find all of them. For larger rings this is generally hopeless.

Comment: Or Can I consider principal ideal generated by every a in ring?

Comment: @Nancy These are *some* ideals. There can be others.

Comment: @egreg how can $\ (1,1)$  generate $\ (1,0)$ or $\ (0,1)$? Since $\ 1$ is its own inverse, so $\ (1,1)^n=(0,0)$ for every $\ n=2k$.

Comment: @ManjoyDas $(1,0)(1,1)=(1,0)$ belongs to the ideal generated by $(1,1)$.